# How to count lines in render function?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to check how many lines of code in render function via any package or simple JavaScript? If yes, how?

I have tried shallow the component and log the length:

```
// Home is a Component
const wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
console.log(wrapper.length);
```

it shows 1.

I want to check how many line of code exists in home component

Comment: Your example above counts instances of that particular component, it doesn't count lines of code in it. And yes, you could do it using a Gulp / Grunt task for example but you'd need to write your own parser I would imagine.

Comment: @James @MayankShukla i want to do it in my `app.test.js` file. i need test that checks render function has less then 25 line

Comment: This isn't possible within JavaScript (to the best of my knowledge). I'm curious, why do you need to get this info?

Comment: @Charlie want to write a test that will only allow 25 line in render function

Comment: I know that, you've said it in the question and again in the comments. As I said, it can't be done in pure JS.

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehmanKhan surely you'd rather today was something that was picked up by a static analyzer rather than a unit test?